# Python plotly - set traces equal except new trace has legend off

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I am currently trying to create a new trace based on an old trace except I want the second trace to have the legend off. The code for trace 1 is:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    mode='lines',
    name='INC',
    line = dict(
        color = ('rgb(0,153,255)'),
        )
)
```

How can I create `trace2` such that it is equal to `trace` except it includes `showlegend=false` ? Essentially, I want `trace2` to be:

```
trace2 = go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        mode='lines',
        name='INC',
        showlegend=false,
        line = dict(
            color = ('rgb(0,153,255)'),
            )
    )
```

I have to do this for several traces. Is there a shortcut I could use after typing `trace2=trace` that would be equivalent? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `copy()` to achieve this easily and add the key you want, as in a simple dict :

```
trace = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    mode='lines',
    name='INC',
    line = dict(
        color = ('rgb(0,153,255)'),
        )
)

trace2 = trace.copy()
trace2['showlegend']=False
print(trace)
print(trace2)

# >>>{'type': 'scatter', 'y': 3, 'mode': 'lines', 'x': 2, 'name': 'INC', 'line': {'color': 'rgb(0,153,255)'}}
# >>>{'showlegend': False, 'type': 'scatter', 'y': 3, 'mode': 'lines', 'x': 2, 'name': 'INC', 'line': {'color': 'rgb(0,153,255)'}}
```